# Will the new Chrome extension restrictions allow local installs of a packaged app?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

Google is changing Chrome's policy to no longer allow installation of extensions in any way other than through the Chrome Web Store. However, their wording is a little unclear. They state:

> We’ll continue to support local extension installs during development as well as installs via Enterprise policy, and **Chrome Apps will also continue to be supported normally.**

But it's unclear whether they mean ChromeOS apps, or packaged apps as defined by an `"app"` section in the `manifest.json`. Do they mean packaged apps can still be installed outside the Chrome store?

http://blog.chromium.org/2013/11/protecting-windows-users-from-malicious.html

Answer (score 0):

"ChromeOS apps" and "packaged apps as defined by an "app" section in the manifest.json" are one and the same thing. And yes, packaged apps can be installed outside the Chrome Store in their unpackaged form (click the "Development mode" checkbox in chrome://extensions page). Otherwise app development would be seriously hindered.

Comment: Your answer does not fit what they say in the blog. They talk about unpacked local installs as different from what happens with Chrome Apps. They claim Chrome apps will be normal and are different from development mode. Do you work for the Chromium team? If so, then the wording is not properly conveying what you say is the true case. Otherwise, are you guessing?

Comment: Sergey is on the chromium team and what he says is correct. Packaged apps are not affected by this policy in any way. Neither of us wrote the blog post.

Comment: @BenWells Thank you, has this information/distinction been added to the official docs?

Comment: Not that I know of. There was discussion internally of creating a FAQ to answer these kind of questions but it hasn't happened yet. I'll let the person involved know about this question (and also point it out to them).

Comment: This was pointed out to me from the linked blog post: "Chrome Apps will also continue to be supported normally". That could probably be spelled out more (i.e. what does "normally" mean).